# python psycopg2 select current_timestamp problem with timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, datetime, psycopg2

I'm calling a simple select to obtain current timestamp with timezone with psycopg2 and it's retrieving UTC time instead of my local time (-3).

datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 13, **20, 49, 47**, 931834, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(**offset=0,** name=None))

In postgresql I'm doing:

```
select current_timestamp
```

This retrieves (Argentina time -3):

```
2021-01-13 17:39:57
```

So this is correct, but in Python:

```
class DatabaseUtils():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dsn = "dbname=my_database user=postgres host=127.0.0.1"
        self.conn, self.cur = self.connect_db()
        self.database_name = "my_table"

    def connect_db(self):
        """
        :param DSN: data source name. ex: "dbname=sigbase user=postgres"
        :return: connection, cursor   < If successful
        """
        try:
            # Connect to the database
            conn = psycopg2.connect(self.dsn)
            # Default encoding is UTF8
            conn.set_client_encoding('UTF8')
            cur = conn.cursor()
        except:
            logger.error(f'Could not connect to database {self.dsn}')
            conn, cur = None, None
        return conn, cur

    def myselect(self):

        query = "select current_timestamp ;"
        self.cur.execute(query)
        records = self.cur.fetchall()
        logger.debug(f"Selected records {records}")
```

Select method retrieves:

```
Selected records [(datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 13, 20, 49, 47, 931834, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)),)]
```

**So datetime object is comming with offset 0, i.e UTC.**
Is it possible to retrieve current timestamp in psycopg2 with the proper timezone?
If not, how can I convert the datetime object timezone?

Comment: By 'in postgresql` do you mean via `psql`? If so is this on the same machine as where the Python code is run? What OS and version of same are you on?

Comment: In  `psql` what does `show timezone` return?

Comment: Yes, I'm using dbeaver to execute postgresql query. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and Python3. It's the same machine.

show timezone gives me: America/Argentina/Cordoba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue in this way:
I added a method in the class init to set the timezone. In this way, the SELECT statements are giving the proper time.

```
def set_timezone(self):
    # Get current time zone.
    timezone = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone().tzname()
    # Set timezone.
    self.cur.execute(f"SET TIME ZONE {timezone};")
```

Result logged in python is:

```
Selected records [(datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 14, 14, 21, 18, 455322, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=-180, name=None)),)]
```

This is correct (Argentina time now).

Extra info:
I based on the psycopg documentation, in the example is telling the timezone first, before the query. I think the select current_time in this library is working in UTC by default.

Source: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#time-zones-handling

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in this way. Setting timezone on every time db connection is a very big hurdle in case if you want it to be in a specific timezone always.

You can just try adding below line in your project **.env** or **settings.py** file.

```
PGTZ='Asia/Kolkata'
```

For more info you can refer here - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html