# current_date via psycopg2/posrtgreSQL is getting the day before, rather the real 'current' date?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I just noticed this behavior and didn't find much clue. Here's the quick testing code

```py
import psycopg2 as pg
import datetime

dbname = "mypo"
user = "mydba"
host = "localhost"
password = "password"

conn = pg.connect(f"dbname='{dbname}' user='{user}' host='{host}' password='{password}'")
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = 'select current_date'
cursor.execute(sql)
c_date = cursor.fetchone()[0]

cursor.close()
conn.close()

print("CURRENT_DATE from DB:", c_date)
print("date.today() from Py:", datetime.date.today())
```

The output is

```
CURRENT_DATE from DB: 2021-12-21
date.today() from Py: 2021-12-22
```

But if I run the same SQL in postgreSQL client directly, I got the result of 2021-12-22, and the versions of each component as below:

```sh
~ % psql mypo
psql (14.1)
Type "help" for help.

mypo=# select current_date;
 current_date
--------------
 2021-12-22
(1 row)

mypo=# exit;

~ % python3 --version
Python 3.9.9
~ %
~ % pip3 freeze | grep psycopg2
psycopg2==2.9.1
```

Did anyone encounter the same ?
By the way, I'm running all these on M1 Mac, not sure if this matters.

---

Supplement outcome as per mentioned in comment section, timezone related trial:

```sh
~ % psql mypo
psql (14.1)
Type "help" for help.

mypo=# select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
       current_timestamp
-------------------------------
 2021-12-22 16:59:09.088675+08
(1 row)

mypo=# exit;
 ~ % python3
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 21 2021, 03:16:13)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> print(datetime.datetime.now())
2021-12-22 16:59:25.097794
>>>
```

Modified python code by changing the sql

```py
sql = "select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
cursor.execute(sql)
print("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from DB:", cursor.fetchone()[0])
print("datetime.now from Python:", datetime.now())
```

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from DB: 2021-12-22 00:57:40.466878-08:00
datetime.now from Python: 2021-12-22 16:57:40.467509
```

It appears psycopg2 result is having 16hours gap, but from CLI the gap doesn't intercept.

Comment: only thing i can think of is to check the time zone of the Postgres server. i'm not sure the details of how to do that, though.

Comment: Good point, let me dig into this route and see what I can find

Comment: Just checked on the postgreSQL timezone setting, it's exactly the same as my OS timezone.

Comment: It almost certainly is timezone related though. Try printing `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to see what it thinks "now" is.

Comment: Just tried: 

sql = "select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",   
output: CURRENT_DATE from DB: 2021-12-21 23:55:18.989029-08:00; 

Meanwhile,  print("date.today() from Py:", datetime.now()) gave me 2021-12-22 15:55:18.989441

The delta's still there

Comment: Maybe psycopg does not take the appropriate time zone. Maybe try to set it as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709643/python-psycopg2-select-current-timestamp-problem-with-timezone

Comment: Wow, cool ! That does solve the problem ! Thanks Stephane

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @StephaneM pointed me to the right post.
The solution is originally in psycopg2 doc: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#time-zones-handling

For my testing code above, adding one line of code before executing actual SQL

```py
cursor.execute("SET TIME ZONE 'Asia/Shanghai'")
```

solve the issue -- 'Asia/Shanghai' is the same timezone of my pqsql.